# How to include sitemap xml in html

Tags: html, sitemap

You can include RSS in html head using

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="" href="" />
```

can I do the same with sitemap? I can't find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this link go to robots.txt file:

```
Sitemap: http://website.com/sitemap.xml
```